# Ring structure on the stable homotopy groups of spheres well-defined?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

The stable homotopy groups of the spheres $\pi_{*}^{s}$ assemble into a graded ring

$\pi_{*}^{s} = \bigoplus_{n\geq 0} \pi_{n}^{s},$

with the graded product defined `in terms of composition'. For example, if $\alpha \in \pi_{i}^{s} $ has representative $[f: S^{n+i} \rightarrow S^{n}]$ and $\beta \in \pi_{j}^{s} $ has representative $[g: S^{n+j} \rightarrow S^{n}]$, then the product $\alpha \cdot \beta \in \pi_{i+j}^{s}$ may be defined as

$\alpha \cdot \beta := [g \circ \Sigma^{j}f : S^{n+i+j} \rightarrow S^{n}]$.

But we could have also defined the product as

$\alpha \cdot \beta := [f \circ \Sigma^{i}g : S^{n+i+j} \rightarrow S^{n}]$.

(The point is that we define the product in terms of a composition, possibly after suspending.)

My question is how do you show that these two definitions define the same product?

Reading the comment to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358068/different-possibilities-defining-eta2-in-the-ring-of-stable-homotopy-groups), one may try to approach this via an [Eckmann-Hilton Duality argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument). But using this argument as stated, one would end up proving that these products are commutative. This is not true, as they are graded commutative.

Maybe there is a `graded' Eckmann-Hilton duality argument I could apply, but my attempts so far have lead me to conclude the above two products only coincide up to sign, which clearly should not me true. I am clearly going wrong somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

I tried looking in the literature, but I could not find anyone who comments on this, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your argument show that the ``up to a sign'' is independent of what you are multiplying? If that is the case, I would just check the sign on the identity product which must trivially agree.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The stable homotopy groups of spheres form a graded commutative ring: elements commute up to a sign, not on the nose, so the order does matter.

Comment: Also, I suspect the Eckmann-Hilton argument is as follows: in a symmetric monoidal category $(C,\otimes,1)$, the Hom set $C(1,1)$ is a monoid in two ways: through the tensor product and through composition. Now one can define the graded Spanier-Whitehead category to have objects the finite pointed spaces and Hom sets the direct sum $\bigoplus_k \mathrm{colim}_{n \rightarrow \infty}[\Sigma^n X,\Sigma^{n+k}Y]$, and this forms a symmetric monoidal category under smash product. Thus you can apply the theorem to the unit $S^0$, which solves your problem

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I am asking whether the two possible definitions of product I have written in the question are the same? I know that the stable homotopy groups of spheres form a graded commutative ring.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Oh, nice. I will have to think about it, but this sounds good. Thanks for your comment :).

Comment: The smash product is also graded commutative, and that should probably inform the Eckmann-Hilton argument.